# Подскажите пожалуйста, что делает код `{% url ... %}`

Tags: python, html, django, html-form

Подскажите. пожалуйста, что делает строка `<а href="{% url 'by_rubric' rubric.pk %)">` в коде? Какую функцию или ссылку нужно передать в url?

```
<div> 
  <а href="{% url 'index' %)">Главная</а> 
  {% for rubric in rubrics %) 
  <а href="{% url 'by_rubric' rubric.pk %)"> 
  {{ rubric.name ))</а> 
  {% endfor %) 
</div>
<form method="post"> 
  {% csrf_token %) 
  {{ form.as_p )) 
  <input type="submit" vаluе="Добавить">
</form>
```

Comment: `<input type="suЬmit" vаluе="Добавить">` откуда у вам там мягкий знак?

Comment: Я код из PDF файла скопировал, а там почему то некоторые буквы заменены, где заметил - изменил

Comment: наверное из книги через Abby Finereader получили pdf

Answer (score 4):

`<а href="{% url 'by_rubric' rubric.pk %}">` - это ссылка в цикле. Эта ссылка будет повторяться *len(rubrics)* раз. В имени ссылки выводится имя рубрики. Сама ссылка, как я понимаю, ведёт к детальному отображению рубрики. Ну т.е в ссылке указано имя адреса куда будет происходить переадресация - это адрес с именем **by_rubric** и еще далее там указан аргумент `rubric.pk`. Соответственно у вас еще есть url-параметр в пути с именем **by_rubric** и, так как в пути есть url-параметр, то его нужно так же передавать, как аргумент в ссылку.

`by_rubric` указывается в параметре `name` в `urlpatterns.py` для путей, где это необходимо. Это применяется для того, чтобы не хардкодить ссылки в коде.

Django будет строить ссылку примерно так:

Допустим rubrics содержит 5 записей(скажем записи title1-title5) и если пройтись по этому списку в цикле, то будет ссылка на каждую запись(5 ссылок будет):

```
title1 (pk=1)
title2 (pk=2)
title3 (pk=3)
title4 (pk=4)
title5 (pk=5)
```

В названии ссылки выводятся имя рубрик, а в скобках, как я говорил выше - аргументы. На каждой итерации цикла подставляется pk каждой рубрики и url-параметр в пути с именем **by_rubric** получает pk каждой рубрики в цикле. Слишком развернуто я ответил :)